# Estoy creando un sistema de historia clinica con fullcalendar quisiera desabilitar las fechas pasadas

Tags: fullcalendar

ESTE ES EL SCRIPT [![la imagen muestra que el martes 2 de marzo puedo agregar una cita y no quisiera que sea asi

```
<script>

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        plugins: [ 'dayGrid', 'interaction', 'timeGrid','list' ],
        header: {
        left: 'prev,next today ',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
         },

        /*funcion click en fecha para mostrar modal*/
         dateClick:function(info){
         limpiarFormulario();


         $('#btnAgregar').prop("disabled",false);
         $('#btnEditar').prop("disabled",true);
         $('#btnBorrar').prop("disabled",true);

         $('#txtFecha').val(info.dateStr);

         $('#exampleModal').modal();

         },

        /*funcion para recuperar datos*/
         eventClick:function(info){

         $('#btnAgregar').prop("disabled",true);
         $('#btnEditar').prop("disabled",false);
         $('#btnBorrar').prop("disabled",false);

         $('#txtID').val(info.event.id);
         $('#txtTitulo').val(info.event.title);
         $('#txtPaciente_id').val(info.event.extendedProps.paciente_id);
         $('#txtMedico_id').val(info.event.extendedProps.medico_id);
         $('#txtEstado_id').val(info.event.extendedProps.estado_id);


         mes =(info.event.start.getMonth()+1);
         dia =(info.event.start.getDate());
         anio =(info.event.start.getFullYear());
         minutos=info.event.start.getMinutes();
         hora=info.event.start.getHours();
         minutos=(minutos<10)?"0"+minutos:minutos;
         hora=(hora<10)?"0"+hora:hora;
         horario =(hora+":"+minutos);

         $('#txtFecha').val(anio+"-"+mes+"-"+dia);
         $('#txtHora').val(horario);
         $('#txtColor').val(info.event.backgroundColor);

         $('#exampleModal').modal();

         },

         events:"{{ url('/eventos/show') }}"

         });

         calendar.setOption('locale', 'Es');
         calendar.render();

         /*botones para agregar, editar y eliminar datos con el controlador*/
        $('#btnAgregar').click(function(){

         ObjEvento=recolectarDatosGUI("POST");

         EnviarInformacion('',ObjEvento);

         });

         $('#btnBorrar').click(function(){

         ObjEvento=recolectarDatosGUI("DELETE");

         EnviarInformacion('/'+$('#txtID').val(),ObjEvento);

         });

         $('#btnEditar').click(function(){

         ObjEvento=recolectarDatosGUI("PATCH");

         EnviarInformacion('/'+$('#txtID').val(),ObjEvento);
         });

         function recolectarDatosGUI(method){

         nuevoEvento={
         id:$('#txtID').val(),
         paciente_id:$('#txtPaciente_id').val(),
         title:$('#txtTitulo').val(),
         medico_id:$('#txtMedico_id').val(),
         estado_id:$('#txtEstado_id').val(),
         color:$('#txtColor').val(),
         textColor:'#FFFFFF',
         start:$('#txtFecha').val()+' '+$('#txtHora').val(),
         end:$('#txtFecha').val()+' '+$('#txtHora').val(),

         "_token": $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content"),
         "_method":method
         }
             return (nuevoEvento);
         }

         /*peticion ajax para enviar informacion*/

         function EnviarInformacion(accion,objEvento){

          $.ajax(
         {
         type:"POST",
         url:"{{ url('/eventos') }}"+accion,
         data:objEvento,
          success:function(msg){

         $('#exampleModal').modal('toggle');
         calendar.refetchEvents();

        },
         error:function(){ alert("Hay un error");}
         }
         );



                                                                                                                                                                                }
         });
 /*funcion para limpiar formulario al elegir otra fecha*/
         function limpiarFormulario() {

            $('#txtID').val('');
            $('#txtTitulo').val('');
            $('#txtFecha').val('');
            $('#txtHora').val('09:00');
            $('#txtColor').val('');
            $('#txtDescripcion').val('');
            $('#txtPaciente_id').val('Seleccione paciente');
            $('#txtMedico_id').val('Seleccione médico');
            $('#txtEstado_id').val('Seleccione estado');
          }


         </script>
```

Comment: estoy trabajando con laravel de php por cierto

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy amplia, por favor centralizala en un problema concreto, por favor lee [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo una posible solución de dos maneras:

1. Usando la propiedad [validRange](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/validRange) del propio fullcalendar. Podrías hacer algo como esto

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    validRange: {
      start: new Date(),
    }
  });
  calendar.render();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/combine/npm/fullcalendar@5.5.1,npm/fullcalendar@5.5.1/main.min.js,npm/fullcalendar@5.5.1/locales-all.min.js,npm/fullcalendar@5.5.1/locales-all.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/combine/npm/fullcalendar@5.5.1/main.min.css,npm/fullcalendar@5.5.1/main.min.css">

<div id="calendar">
</div>
```

2. Evaluar directamente el método select cuando el usuario haga su selección y determinar si es menor a tu fecha de inicio o mayor a tu fecha de finalización. Recuerda que select te da el startStr y el endStr y decidir si lo dejas seleccionar o no.

Te dejo este ejemplo en [CodePen](https://codepen.io/gaidygomez/pen/oNYJwjW?editors=1000) para que lo veas más claro.

Espero te sirva. Saludos

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias por tu ayuda !! use la propiedad validRange y enseguida se ejecutó como queria

Comment: Buenísimo, me alegro por ti.